# What is the allowed distance between service entrance and breaker box?

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel

What is the distance allowed between where the service wires enter your home and the breaker box?

Comment: [This site](http://ecmweb.com/code-basics/electrical-services-part-2) says that there's no limit specified in the NEC, but there may be a limit imposed by your local jurisdiction. Since I can't vouch for this source (or the current applicability of an article published 6 years ago), I'll let someone with access to the NEC to post an more definitive answer.

Comment: Isn't it <5% for the drop?

Comment: Moot the problem by getting a meter pan with a main breaker in it.  Kris he's asking about length not voltage drop, there are other factors too, notably physical protection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NEC simply says as close as practical. Some locations do impose an actual distance number. Most areas have a limit of 5-6 feet into the structure to the main panel/disconnect.

Your local authority/inspector will be the only one who can tell you for sure.

Comment: Thanks.  Owing the the layout of my utility room, I'm pretty sure it's going to be about 7-8' to where I can locate the panel to have the required working space in front of it.